Deserialize escaped string into Vec<String> with serde
Newbie in Rust here.
I'm having some difficulties parsing a escaped json string into a Option<Vec<String>>.
I have an api that's returning a collection of items, and one of the properties contains an array of strings, however, the array is escaped as a string. Here an example, please check the keywords property.
        {
            "id": "123123132",
            "properties": {
                "createdate": "2023-06-25T03:10:43.312Z",
                "description": "Lorem Impsum ......",
                "keywords": "[\"keyword1\", \"keyword2\", \"keyword3\"]"
            },
            "createdAt": "2023-06-25T03:10:43.312Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-04-03T14:40:20.360Z",
        },
        {
            "id": "789789789",
            "properties": {
                "createdate": "2023-06-25T03:10:43.312Z",
                "description": "Another description ......",
                "keywords": null
            },
            "createdAt": "2023-06-25T03:10:43.312Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-04-03T14:40:20.360Z",
        },

Sadly, I do not have any control over the API, so I was trying to parse it as a string array. Also, that property is not mandatory, so, sometimes can contain null values.
I have tried implementing the following code in Rust:

fn deserialize_keywords<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<Vec<String>>, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s: &str = de::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    match serde_json::from_str(s) {
        Result::Ok(v) => Result::Ok(Some(v)),
        Result::Err(e) => Result::Ok(None)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ItemProperties {
    id: String,
    description: Option<String>,

    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_keywords")]
    keywords: Option<Vec<String>>,

    #[serde(alias = "createdate")]
    created_date: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Item {
    pub id: String,
    pub properties: ItemProperties,
    #[serde(alias = "createdAt")]
    pub created_at: String,
    #[serde(alias = "updatedAt")]
    pub updated_at: String,
}



#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct TypeResponse {
    results: Vec<Item>,
    total: usize,
}

let response = self.client.post("https://api.com/items")
            .send()
            .await?
            .json::<TypeResponse>()
            .await?;


However, when I try that I have the following error:
Error: error decoding response body: invalid type: null, expected a borrowed string at line 1 column 349

Caused by:
    invalid type: null, expected a borrowed string at line 1 column 349

I actually tried a few more things, but nothing has worked so far.
Any idea how can I achieve it?

In this case, you can probably write let s: Option<String> = ... (I don't think a &str can work at all due to escape sequences) and then check if it's None.

Aside: Unless there's a difference between Some(vec![]) and None it'd be simpler to just deserialize into Vec<String>. It doesn't allocate in the empty case either.

As BalllpointBen already mentioned, you cannot deserialize a JSON string with escape sequences into &str so you have to replace it with String and since it may not be there (null is possible) you'll have to deserialize into an Option<String>:
use serde::{de, Deserialize};
fn deserialize_keywords<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<String>, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let Some(keywords_string): Option<String> = de::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)? else {
        return Ok(vec![]);
    };

    let Ok(keywords) = serde_json::from_str(&keywords_string) else {
        return Ok(vec![]);
    };

    Ok(keywords)
}

// here follows a more minimal example I used to test.
const JSON: &str =
    r#"[{ "keywords": "[\"keyword1\", \"keyword2\", \"keyword3\"]"}, {"keywords": null}]"#;

fn main() {
    let foos: Vec<Foo> = serde_json::from_str(JSON).unwrap();
    dbg!(foos);
}


#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_keywords")]
    keywords: Vec<String>,
}

I've additionally removed the ambiguous representation of no keywords (Some(vec![]) and None) since that's unlikely what you want.

just posting what finally worked for me.
Thank you @BallpointBen and @cafce25.
I finally used this approach here, because apparently the api also returned in the same keywords field comma-separated strings.
fn deserialize_keywords<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<String>, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s: Option<String> = Option::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    match s {
        Some(v) => {
            let Ok(keywords) = serde_json::from_str(&v) else {
                // We handle cases when the keywords are coming as comma separated strings
                let items: Vec<String> = v.split(",")
                    .map(|i| { String::from(i) })
                    .collect();
                return Ok(items);
            };

            Ok(keywords)
        }
        None => Ok(vec![])
    }
}

Hope this helps someone!
